# R/MASS kde2d and bandwidth.nrd

Tags: r, kernel-smoothing, heatmap

First off, I didn't know whether to post this here or on SO. I tossed a coin and ended here.

Second, I'm trying to get a grip on the `kde2d` function in the MASS library. I've read the manual on `kde2d` and `bandwidth.nrd` (which `kde2d` uses to compute its "vector of bandwidths for x and y directions").
In the manual page for `bandwidth.nrd` it says that that function is "A well-supported rule-of-thumb for choosing the bandwidth of a Gaussian kernel density estimator". Why would I want to use this function specific?

Also, I'm doing a project on cell data and spatial data (i.e. GPS coordinates of phones and the cell tower they've been on). How well does `bandwidth.nrd` work with specifically *this* kind of data and why? Are there alternatives?

Lastly, I've found that the MASS implementation of `bandwidth.nrd` multiplies its result by 4 "for compatibility reasons". I found that dividing the result of `kde2d` by 4 gives me a better-looking image (i.e. I can see roads and highway interchanges, not so much when I use the result as-is).